Is "practice" in "practice crafts" similar to pratice in "practice the guitar" or "practice law/medicine"?

The men practised various traditional crafts, such as carving toys out of bone.

What does this sentence imply? Did these men practice crafts to get better or to make a living? Are both interpretations correct?

What do you actually not understand? They could be making decorations for their huts. Who knows? This is really not about English.

I've tried to make myself clear under Paul's answer.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practice

As always, the meaning of an isolated scrap cannot be known without context. It could mean merely that the men occasionally spent time engaged in crafts, perhaps as hobbies or simply to pass the time. It could also mean that they engaged in those activities in order to learn them, though this interpretation would probably be expressed differently by a native speaker. And yes, it could mean that their engaging in the crafts was for the purpose of trade—to sell their output or services to others—or out of generosity or charity.

So it can mean either? I mean when we say practice medicine, it can only mean "work in the medical field" right? It can't mean "I read/do things related to medicine  so that I'll become better at it" (like the way we use practice in "practice playing football"). And when we say "practice playing football", it can't mean "work as a footballer". I mean I thought "practice" would only deliver one of the two meanings in a sentence, but "practice" in "practice crafts" can mean either?

It means that they did that habitually, with no reference to the learning process but not necessarily to make a living (though that is the implication in "practice law/medicine).

I disagree that making a living is always implied by the verb 'practice' in connection with professions such law, medicine, dentistry, etc.  It does mean 'to do work of a particular type for which a lot of training is necessary', but such professionals can, and often do, carry the work out for no payment, and someone practising magic usually does not do it to get a living.

I don't think you (Percival) can make this assumption. It definitely depends on the context. If the men weren't familiar with the traditional crafts, they could have been learning. Not all men are skilled at everything!
